# 1's and 2's complement of 0

Tags: binary

In the Morris Mano's book on Digital Circuits Edition 3, it is defined that r's complement for N=0 is 0 and r-1 complement is not even defined.

But lets say r = base = 2

Then 2'd complement of 0, based on his formula is $r^n - N$ where $n$ is number of digits is $2^1 - 0 = 2$. This also makes sense because $(0)'' = (0)' + 1 \to 1 + 1 \to 10$ in binary and $2$ in decimal

Now coming on to 1's complement, the formula is $r^n - r^{-m} - N$ where $n$ is same as in 2's complement and $m$ is the number of digits after decimal. So, $2^1 - 2^0 - 0$ gives $2 - 1 - 0 \to 1$ which is also correct.

Does that mean that first line which is in the book is incorrect? For your information, I am reading the book addressed for Indian students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero in 1's complement is the same as zero in normal binary `0000 00000` but there's a weird quirk of 1's complement. In 1's complement you can get the negative version a number by flipping all of its bits so that means you can flip all the bits in zero to get `1111 1111` which has a value of -0.

2's complement avoids this problem by changing how you convert a number to negative. In 2's complement you make a number negative by flipping all the bits then adding 1. Here's what happens when you try to convert zero to a negative number with 2's complement:

1. you start with `0000 00000`
2. you flip all the bits to get `1111 1111`
3. you add 1 which overflows it back to `0000 00000`

**So to answer your question:**

The 1's complement of 0 is `0000 00000` and `1111 1111`

The 2's complement of 0 is `0000 00000`

Comment: I see, so main thing is to disregard the overflown bit. Since we start with 1 bit, 2's complement of `0` is 10. So there is an overflow and we need to confine our result in the same number of bits. Which gives `0`. Hence when N=0, 2's complement is 0.

Answer (score 0):

> I see, so main thing is to disregard the overflown bit.

No, we don't ignore the "sign" digit. Like positive numbers having an infinite number of leading zeros, negative numbers in ***r***  and ***r - 1*** format have an infinite number of leading ***(r - 1)***'s. That is why we sign extend when storing a signed number into a larger storage object.